# Count values in second and third column where first column value is constant/same

Tags: text-processing

I want to count values/word occurrence in second and third column of a tab delim txt file, where first column value is same

Input file:

```
GeneA Pathogenic snp
GeneA Pathogenic snp
GeneA Benign indel
GeneA Likely_pathogenic snp
GeneA Pathogenic    indel
GeneB Benign    snp
GeneB Pathogenic    snp
GeneB Benign    indel
GeneC  Benign   snp
GeneC  Likely_pathogenic    snp
```

Expected Output:(tabular format)

```
| Pathogenic | Benign | Likely_Pathogenic | snp | indel |
 ------------|--------|-------------------|-----|-------|
|GeneA|     3|       1|                  1|    3|      2|
|GeneB|     1|       2|                  0|    2|      1|
|GeneC|     0|       1|                  1|    2|      0|
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting (remove these unnecessary html tags and format as `code`). Then please show us what you tried and how it did not work.

Comment: So, you want `html`  output or what do you mean by "tabular format"?

Comment: I can do that with Ruby. Let me know if that works. Because there are no programming language / shell mentioned.

Comment: @pLumo: not in html format, table with second/third col value should be used as header and count of these values should be mentioned with unique gene name in col first.

Comment: @S.Goswami Basically I am trying to do it with perl, but if ruby works that would also be fine. thank you

Comment: what have you tried so far? you really want the output as showing in your question? or you just wanted to use our table feature for that?

Comment: @αғsнιη The original edit actually came from me, where I removed the previous (and non-working) HTML tags the OP tried to use for table formatting, and replaced it with the Markdown table format. It was subsequently edited by someone else into a code block, but I doubt _that_ is what the OP wanted ...

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` script like the what's shown below would collect the data from the given file and count how many times each "type" (columns two and on) occurs for each "name" (the first column).  It outputs a simple CSV-like format that could be imported into other programs assuming none of the input data contains embedded commas.

```c
{
        genes[$1] = 1
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
                types[$i] = 1
                counts[$1,$i]++
        }
}

END {
        OFS = ","

        $0 = "name"
        for (t in types)
                $(NF+1) = header[++n] = t
        print

        for (g in genes) {
                $0 = g
                for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
                        $(NF+1) = counts[g,header[i]]+0
                print
        }
}
```

The `genes` and `types` arrays are associative arrays that contain the names and the types as keys.  The `counts` array counts how many times a specific name and type has occurred as a pair in the input.

The `END` block creates and outputs the header and then iterates over all gene names and outputs the collected counts for each type.

Testing this:

```
$ awk -f script file
name,indel,Benign,Likely_pathogenic,snp,Pathogenic
GeneA,2,1,1,3,3
GeneB,1,2,0,2,1
GeneC,0,1,1,2,0
```

```
$ awk -f script file | column -t -s,
name   indel  Benign  Likely_pathogenic  snp  Pathogenic
GeneA  2      1       1                  3    3
GeneB  1      2       0                  2    1
GeneC  0      1       1                  2    0
```

```
$ awk -f script file | csvlook
| name  | indel | Benign | Likely_pathogenic | snp | Pathogenic |
| ----- | ----- | ------ | ----------------- | --- | ---------- |
| GeneA |     2 |      1 |              True |   3 |          3 |
| GeneB |     1 |      2 |             False |   2 |          1 |
| GeneC |     0 |      1 |              True |   2 |          0 |
```

(If you don't want [`csvlook`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.6/scripts/csvlook.html) to infer the type from the data, us it with its `-I` option.)

Answer (score 0):

As told in the Comment box, Ruby is permitted, I've a standalone solution, it doesn't require piping different programs:

##### Program

```
data = <<~'EOF'
    GeneA Pathogenic snp
    GeneA Pathogenic snp
    GeneA Benign indel
    GeneA Likely_pathogenic snp
    GeneA Pathogenic    indel
    GeneB Benign    snp
    GeneB Pathogenic    snp
    GeneB Benign    indel
    GeneC  Benign   snp
    GeneC  Likely_pathogenic    snp
EOF

hash, header1, header2 = {}, [], []

data.each_line { |x|
    fields = x.split("\s")
    field = hash[fields[0].to_sym] ||= [{}, {}]

    field[0].merge!(fields[1] => 1) { |key, val1, val2| val1 + val2 }
    field[1].merge!(fields[2] => 1) { |key, val1, val2| val1 + val2 }
    header1 << fields[1]
    header2 << fields[2]
}

headers = header1.tap(&:uniq!).concat(header2.tap(&:uniq!))
header = '| ' + headers.join(' | ') + ' | '

puts header, ?- * header.length

hash.each { |k, v|
    v0, v1 = v[0], v[1]

    print "| #{k} |"
    headers.each_with_index { |x, i|
        out = "#{(v0[x] || v1[x]).to_i} |"
        print i == 0 ? out.rjust(5) : out.rjust(x.length + 3)
    }
    puts
}
```

##### Execute:

```
$ ruby thisFile.rb
```

##### Output:

```
| Pathogenic | Benign | Likely_pathogenic | snp | indel | 
----------------------------------------------------------
| GeneA |  3 |      1 |                 1 |   3 |     2 |
| GeneB |  1 |      2 |                 0 |   2 |     1 |
| GeneC |  0 |      1 |                 1 |   2 |     0 |
```

You might yell at those `rjust(5)`, `rjust(x.length + 3)`, because they are hardcoded. Actually those are for the `' | '`, which are hardcoded as well. If you add one more space, you add one to the numbers. It won't break if data changes.

Instead of having `data <<~EOF...`, you can read a file containing the data with `data = (ARGV[0] && File.readable?(ARGV[0])) ? IO.read(ARGV[0]) : ''` - here data is read from the filename passed as argument. Should work with every data, but the alignment is done on basis of the header. A small modification of this code can align data based on the biggest field. But for now I think this will get your job done.